# K×H is Isomorphic to A4?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Prove \ Disapprove : There exist two non-trivial sub groups $K$ and $H$ such that $A_4\cong K×H$:

My intuition was to disprove this claim by saying that $H$ or $K$ must be the Klein sub-group and every other sub-group in $A_4$ is not normal.

But I don't see how it gets me anywhere.

Comment: Here's another approach. Since $A_4$ has no subgroup of order $6$, every proper subgroup of $A_4$ is abelian. Then the result follows since $A_4$ is nonabelian.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite on the right track, and you only need to remember that if a group is a direct product of two of its subgroups then these subgroups are normal...

Comment: How can I prove that if a group is a direct product of two of its subgroups then these subgroups are normal

Comment: Please do read *carefully* the definition of "direct product" and what it follows from it in any relevant link, say in "algebraic structure" here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups